# Php Session Variable Deleted After Post

Tags: php

This code is supposed to save a random number into a session varible when generateCode is pressed

It does generate it and store in the variable but when i try to acces is from the `if(isset($_POST['confirmCode'])){` it is empty

```php
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['generateCode'])){
$_SESSION["key"] =  mt_rand(100000, 999999);
}

if(isset($_POST['confirmCode'])){
   die($_SESSION["key"]);
}
?>
```

```html
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="confcode" placeholder="Confirmation Code">
<input type="submit" name="confirmCode" value="Confirm">
<input type="submit" name="generateCode" value="Generate">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Does anybody know how i can make a variable that stays some time even after post request

Edit:
So to get this clear confirmCode is a button to submit the code entered in a `<input type="text></input>` But i decided to not include the code to get the content if confCode because this question is about how to keep a variable generated by mt_rand even after  `<input type="submit">` is pressed

Comment: Use `var_dump` to debug, don't `echo` or `die`. You get more information this way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the button, PHP actually puts the name and value in the parameters.

The problem is with the `die` function. It expects either a message (string) or a **status code** (integer). When you generate the random number **it interprets the message as a number** (status code) instead of a string (message). To make sure it interprets the key as a string you could wrap it in a `strval()` function like this:
`die(strval($_SESSION["key"]));`

Comment: thank you this fixed it, im kinda new to php and didnt think about this